# Git: Branching iOS app that uses storyboards but how to prevent conflicts?

Tags: ios, objective-c, git, storyboard

I have an app (App1) that is done. We are using the same app to launch a totally different service (AppX). But, I want all bug fixes in App1 to also be updated in AppX (AppX will follow App1 on github).

The issue is most of the iOS app was done in Storyboard (For those non iOS people, storyboards are pain in the ass on github when you have conflicts as they are kind of like a WYSIWYG editor). So I need to make lots of changes in AppX's storyboard to make it look like a totally different app. But, then when I update App1 storyboard I don't want it updating AppX storyboard or conflicting.

My question is A) what is the best way to handle this. B) I am thinking create a new storyboard in AppX that at start is a duplicate of App1's storyboard then modify it, which will prevent any conflicts. C) Is this the best way or is there a better way?  D) Any good examples of how to do 2nd storyboard?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tough one. It's easier to manage during production rather than in the situation you're in. What I'd recommend is trying to merge the storyboard from App1 to AppX anyway. Yes, there will be conflicts. If you've managed your storyboards in such a way that none is a large monstrous mess of XML, then it probably won't be as much of a nightmare to go through the source for each storyboard and sort out the conflicts.

On the other hand, if you are just trying to avoid collisions altogether, then be sure the storyboards from the two apps have different names.

I could be misunderstanding your question, so please feel free to clarify.

Edit: regarding your comment below about tractors and pets, there arethings you can do:

1) Create separate branches. The storyboards for each project will be on separate branches and you won't have conflicts as long as you never merge them. But I woulnd't recommend this because it will be more difficult to keep the other source files consistent.

2) Create another target in your XCode project. There are lots of questions and answers already out there about this topic. But you can have two targets with each having it's own storyboard, while both sharing the same source code. This would be easier to manage rather than trying to track two separate apps across two different branches.

Comment: You got it right. Do you know how to change the storyboard app wide? I assume it done in AppDelegate?  Or do I have to tell each viewcontroller to use AppZ storyboard. Is there a way to just say in AppDelegate... hey just use AppZ storyboard app wide?

Comment: Do you mean you have multiple storyboards in the project, but you just want to use one of them for AppX?

Comment: No. I have working iOS. I now need to create a new branched version of this app (first app was selling tractors, this new app is selling pets). Now I want all bug fixes from tractors to also be fixed in pets app. But the pets app UI/Storyboards needs to be different (colors and text only). When I make UI/Storyboard changes in tractor I DO NOT want them updating the Pets storyboard.